# Quick JQuery Question - change value with .find

Tags: jquery

I have this code.

```
$(".setHide").click(function () {
  $('.newSet').find('input[type=text]').val('');
  $(this).parent().hide();
```

It will detect a click on a link with the .setHide class and then:

1) Empty any field inside the .newSet div

2) Hide the .newSet div

My issue is that I have several .newSet divs open, so all the fields in all the divs get emptied.  How can I empty only the fields in the current div in which the .setHide link is clicked?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: what is your html structure? is .newSet inside .setHide?

Comment: can you provide some html of you page. I need to know the structure of your DOM

Comment: Is the `.newSet` element the one with the input you want to clear? Or all child elements within it?

Comment: maybe this would help, not sure though `$(this).find('.newSet').find('input[type=text]').val('');`

Comment: Do you have id's set in the .newSet elements?  Is there information in the link itself that can tell you which input you want to clear?  Those things (id's and info in the link potentially, or the link's id) will make this much easier to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the parents() method, see how it works at the [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

```
$(".setHide").click(function () {
  $(this).parents(".newSet")
         .hide()
         .find('input[type=text]')
         .val('');
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this:

```
$('.newSet').find('input[type=text]').val('');
```

try this:

```
$(this).find('input[type=text]').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".setHide").click(function(){
  var $div = $(this).parent().hide();
  $('.newSet input[type="text"]', $div).val('');
});
```

This will clear all inputs inside `.newSet` that are inside the parent of `.setHide`.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the selector an element to start searching from and in this instance you want it to start from the current element.

```
$('.newSet', this).find('input[type=text]').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).closest('.newSet').find('input[type=text]').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.setHide').click(function() {
  var $newSet = $('.newSet', $(this));
  $newSet.hide().find('input[type=text]').val('');
});
```